# Selecting one number from the range

Tags: php

I have a trivial question for you but I can not deal with the matches myself.

more precisely - I have a problem with writing a condition that will only be fulfilled when specific parameters occur.

say, I have three thresholds: 2000, 15325, 500000
each of them has an appropriate level

user points are, for example: 16,000

I want it to search for the appropriate level and assign it to the user after reaching the threshold

I unfortunately have a problem with the condition of fulfilling the activity, because the condition

user points> = point threshold

shows me all levels, but

user points <= point threshold

it does not show anything, it does not fulfill the assumption of the script

```
function chooseLevel($dbh) {

    $userPoints = getPoints($dbh, 3);
    $levels = getLevels($dbh);

    foreach($levels as $required) {

        if($userPoints >= $required["points"]) {
            $level = $required["level"];
        }

    }

    return $level;

}
```

Comment: are thresholds values dynamic or static, if its static then you can use if elseif condition for number of thresholds, if its dynamic then you can store them in array and compare the value in loop.

Comment: these are static values. I do exactly as you said, it's all about the correct condition, because all the numbers actually meet it

Comment: i guess you need to use between condition like eg: for value 5 , if its greater than 3 and smaller than 6, use 6 and so on for each

Comment: I did it. I came up with the idea to check if it is> = create an array from it and then return the largest value from it

Comment: Reverse the order …? Check if the user’s points are more than 500000, if yes break out of loop, if not check if the user’s points are more than 15325, ...